# C++ Programming (If Else Statement) won't output properly

Tags: c++, if-statement

This is my If Else Statement for my homework but it doesn't work the way I expected it to be.

When I enter 82 as the grade, it says "Your grade is = ú". Instead of 'B', it displays a character which I didn't declare. Same goes to the others.

Instead of 'A' - @
Instead of 'C' - ╬
Instead of 'D' - (shows nothing)
Instead of 'F' - ″

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()

{
 int score;
 char grade;
 char A, B, C, D, F;

 cout << "Enter your total score: ";
 cin >> score;

if (score >= 85)
grade=A;

else if (score >= 75)
grade=B;

else if (score >= 65)
grade=C;

else if (score >= 55)
grade=D;

else
grade=F;

   cout << "Your grade is = " << grade << endl;


return 0;

cin.get();

}
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: `char A, B, C, D, F;` declares variables which have an undetermined value at run-time. Instead, consider `grade = 'A';`, etc.

Comment: what is use for char variable A,B,C,D,F ? you can directly assign `grade='A'`, `grade='B'` and so on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You declare these variables, but never set them to anything

```
char A, B, C, D, F;
```

You should assign values to them

```
const char A = 'A';
const char B = 'B';
const char C = 'C';
const char D = 'D';
const char F = 'F';
```

Although in this case, even the above may be superfluous. You could simply do

```
if (score >= 85)
    grade = 'A';
else if (score >= 75)
    grade = 'B';
else if (score >= 65)
    grade = 'C';
else if (score >= 55)
    grade = 'D';
else
    grade = 'F';
```

Then you can get rid of the `char` variables all together.

Answer (score 4):

You have declared variables without initialize them:

```
char A = 'A';
char B = 'B';
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Try This code

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()

{
 int score;
  char grade;
  cout << "Enter your total score: ";
  cin >> score;

 if (score >= 85)
 grade='A';

 else if (score >= 75)
 grade='B';

 else if (score >= 65)
 grade='C';

 else if (score >= 55)
 grade='D';

 else
 grade='F';

 cout << "Your grade is = " << grade << endl;

 getch();
 return 0;


}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't explain the problem with original code